# Sending a workflow email from an Organization wide email account Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on a workflow to send an email when a record (Custom Entity) is created or modified. While setting the step for sending an email, I noticed that From Email Field is tied to Users. But what I need is a generic email account from which this email will be sent, something like "support@mycompany.com". Do I need to create this user in the system or is there an easy way out to send emails through generic account without adding it as a user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a Queue with valid email address, approve the email for the Queue and select this queue for 'From' lookup in your email step. You don't have to create an user in CRM.

Answer (score 1):

You can define user and queue in from field of outbound emails. So I would suggest to create a queue for this purpose and you will need no additional user i.e. new license.